# How to prevent automatic page refresh in JavaScript when there's no user interaction or access to the source code?

Tags: javascript, console, refresh

I'm attempting to prevent an automatic page refresh occurring on a website without direct user interaction and lacking access to the source code for modifications.

I've tried various approaches within the browser console to address this automatic refresh but haven't yet found an effective solution. Here are some of the approaches I've attempted:

1. Overriding the setInterval function to try halting the intervals.

   window.setInterval = function() {
   // Do nothing or perform some alternative action
   };
2. Using the beforeunload event to cancel the reload behavior, but these rely on a button, form, or link interaction from the user. In this case, however, there is no user interaction, just automatic reloading.

[https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/71301/evitar-refresco-de-página-al-enviar-formulario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/71301/evitar-refresco-de-p%C3%A1gina-al-enviar-formulario)

[https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/411167/como-evitar-que-la-pagina-se-recargue-la-página-cuando-de-click-en-una-caja-de](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/411167/como-evitar-que-la-pagina-se-recargue-la-p%C3%A1gina-cuando-de-click-en-una-caja-de)

[https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/41515/evitar-que-la-página-se-recargue-al-presionar-f5-con-javascript/611010#611010](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/41515/evitar-que-la-p%C3%A1gina-se-recargue-al-presionar-f5-con-javascript/611010#611010)

[https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/71301/evitar-refresco-de-página-al-enviar-formulario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/71301/evitar-refresco-de-p%C3%A1gina-al-enviar-formulario)

3. Attempting to identify active intervals, but without success:

   // Store the original setInterval function
   const originalSetInterval = window.setInterval;

   // Override setInterval to store interval IDs
   let activeIntervals = [];
   window.setInterval = function(callback, interval) {
   const intervalId = originalSetInterval(callback, interval);
   activeIntervals.push(intervalId);
   return intervalId;
   };

   // Then, display IDs of active intervals
   console.log("Active Intervals:", activeIntervals);
4. Trying to halt the refresh using clearInterval:

   // Attempt to stop automatic refresh
   clearInterval(window.setInterval);
   clearTimeout(window.setTimeout);

It's important to note that there's no direct user interaction triggering this refresh, and I don't have access to modify the HTML or the source code of the page. Therefore, I'm utilizing console options.

Are there other strategies or methods that could be utilized to stop this automatic refresh in JavaScript without requiring user interaction or access to the source code?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that worked to stop the automatic page refresh in my case! Here's the code I used in the browser console:

```
// Stop automatic refresh using the beforeunload event and clearInterval
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.returnValue = 'Customize your message here!';
    return event.returnValue;
});

for (let i = 1; i < 99999; i++) {
    clearInterval(i);
}
```

This solution leverages the beforeunload event to prevent the automatic refresh by preventing its default behavior and customizing a message for the user. Additionally, it uses clearInterval to stop the intervals, which was crucial to prevent continuous page reloads.